# How to eleminate the space between bibitems using memoir?

Tags: bibliographies, memoir

I am trying to change the font size and the spacing of bibitems using the `memoir` class. As the following command (for what ever reason) did not work

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
```

I tried those two (I am happy to avoid an extra package):

```
\renewcommand{\biblistextra}{\footnotesize}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{-\parsep}
```

The latter is recommended in the [memoir manual](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) (p. 301). The Problem is that setting the length of `bibitemsep` does not work when I set the font size as above. What did I wrong?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setmainlanguage[spelling=old,babelshorthands=true,script=latin]{german}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\renewcommand{\biblistextra}{\footnotesize}

\def\bibindent{1.5em}
\def\bibitemindent{-.5em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@biblabel}[1]{\kern\bibitemindent}
\makeatother 

\makeatletter
\let\old@biblabel\@biblabel
\def\@biblabel#1{\old@biblabel{#1}\kern\bibindent}
\let\old@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1{\old@bibitem{#1}\leavevmode\kern-\bibindent}
\makeatother

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\chapter{Test, nothing else}
\section{Don't wast you time reading this!}
\Blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\blindtext
\section{Test124}
\Blindtext
\chapter{Test2}
\Blindtext \Blindtext \Blindtext
 \begin{thebibliography}{8}
 \bibitem{Acham}  Acham, Karl: {\textit{Analytische Geschichtsphilosophie.}} Eine kritische Einführung, Freiburg/München 1974. 

 \bibitem{Acham1969}  —, {\textit{Subjektives Interesse und historische Objektivität.}} {\textit{Ein Beitrag zur Konfundierung von Erleben und Erkennen im Hinblick auf die Geschichtswissenschaften,}} in: Zeitschrift für philosophische Forschung 23 (1969), S.\,47–72. 

 \bibitem{Adorno}  Adorno, Theodor W.: {\textit{Negative Dialektik,}} in: —, Gesammelte Schriften, herausgegeben von Rolf Tiedemann, Bd.\,6, Frankfurt a.\,M.\,2003. 

 \bibitem{Ankersmit}  Ankersmit, Frank: {\textit{Wahrheit in Literatur und Geschichte,}} in: Küttler/Rüsen/Schulin (Hrsg.): Geschichtsdiskurs, Bd.\,5, Frankfurt a.\,M.\,1999, S.\,337–360. 

 \bibitem{Asmuth}  Asmuth, Christoph: {\textit{Der Empirismus und die kritische Philosophie Kants.}} Zur zweiten ›Stellung des Gedankens zur Objektivität‹ im enzyklopädischen ›Vorbegriff‹ der spekulativen Logik, in: Denker/Sell/Zaborowski (Hrsg.): Der Vorbegriff aus Hegels Enzyklopädie der philosophischen Wissenschaften im Grundrisse (1830), Freiburg i.Br.\,2010. 

 \bibitem{Angehrn}  Angehrn, Emil: {\textit{Freiheit und System bei Hege}}l, Berlin 1977. 

 \bibitem{Angehrn1985}  —, {\textit{Geschichte und Identität,}} Berlin 1985. 

 \bibitem{Angehrn1991}  —, {\textit{Geschichtsphilosophie,}} Stuttgart 1991. 
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, it's a additional `\parskip`, which generates the space you obtain (and don't want to appear)

Comment: @daleif I am not using `biblatex` in the example.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Any Idea how to get rid of it? O where it does come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
\renewcommand{\biblistextra}{
  \footnotesize
  \itemsep=\bibitemsep
  \parsep=0pt
}
```

Basically `\biblistextra` should be handled with care. The default value is `\itemsep=\bibitemsep`

Comment: Oh, yes, this is a good idea... I forgot, that it's an 'ordinary' list

Comment: It is always a lot easier to just look in the code ;-)

Comment: I did, but I cured the symptom, not the cause, to speak with Frank'N'Furter :D

Comment: Ooh yeah, Let's Do The Time Warp Again. Need solution, but to get rid of the extra space entirely  I had to put `-4pt` isn't that strange.

Comment: Erh, the above should remove all spaces, especially if bibitemsep is zero. So if you need - 4pt, please provide a mwe that shows that exact document.

Comment: @user5950, forgot to tag you in the comment above

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The example posted in the question shows the problem.

Comment: @user5950, no it does not, it still uses your version of `\biblistextra`. Even if I substitute `\biblistextra` I do not see the need to use `-4pt`. So please be more specific.